# Multiple domains for one website with multiple languages

Tags: laravel, hosting, web-hosting, multiple-domains

I have 3 domains in 3 different languages and I want to point them to one website.

I want to ask hosting provider to point all domains to one application (code - same place/folder on hosting/server). Is this a right solution for this case, or should I proceed differently?

1. domain.tech - english
2. domain.sk - slovak
3. domain.es - spanish

I think it doesn't affect SEO since for every domain there would be different content (same content but different language).

I want .sk and .es domain to be geographically oriented.

I want .tech to be international domain with CDN service.

I want to approach same database and use same local assets (images).

Are there any negatives in option I am considering? Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Why not only 1 domain and 3 subdomains? sk.domain, es.domain, tech.domain?

Comment: I mean why yes? It is the same I would need to point these subdomains also to one point in hosting/server. And also more shallow reason, it looks better. What am I trying to find out if the option I want to do affects SEO negatively or if there is any better solution to what am I trying to do?

Comment: In my opinion, I don't see any problem. That's how it works. That's the approach, it only changes the front depending on the language (with SetLocale) that depends on the domain. But always pointing at the same project